# Correct Multidimensional array format to get output if exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, I'm probably going about this in the wrong way, so before I go any further, i thought I'd check with some experts.

Previously, after searching the DB I'd create an array with the array name of the date and there would only be 1 array per date.  This could then be called and displayed on the appropriate part of the calendar.
But there will now potentially be multiple entries per date and I am trying to change to a multi-dimensional array.

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT stoname, date, hours1, hours2 FROM table WHERE MONTH(date)=? AND YEAR(date)=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $month, $year);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($sto_name, $DB_date, $hours1, $hours2);

while ($stmt->fetch())
{
//Loop through to make new array corresponding to date in database
$foo="_".str_replace("-","",$DB_date);      //take the "-" outta the date

${$foo}[$sto_name]=array(
                    'sto_name'=>$sto_name,
                    'hours1'=>$hours1,
                    'hours2'=>$hours2);
}
$stmt->close();
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, although it does seem to work ok.  However, it then makes it hard to access the arrays as the `[$sto_name]` is unknown and it appears I can't use numeric bits to call an associative array, e.g. `$20160316[0]`.  In the output, I'd need to check if an array exists for that date irrespective of the [$sto_name], then can foreach through to print the array.

I had thought about something like:

```
${$foo}=array(
                    array(
                    'sto_name'=>$sto_name,
                    'hours1'=>$hours1,
                    'hours2'=>$hours2),
                    );
```

But then on the mysqli while loop it presumably overwrites the first array if there's a second array with the same date/$foo.

Comment: to resolve this:-`But then on the mysqli while loop it presumably overwrites the first array if there's a second array with the same date/$foo`  change `${$foo}[$sto_name]` to `${$foo}[$sto_name][]` and check

Comment: To explain @Anant you are assigning the array each time. He is give you the code to append to the array each time.

Comment: @MECU you are telling me or to OP? it's confusing. just read once your comment

Comment: @Anant I was talking to devsie, Just giving the terms to explain what you were saying. I see and apologize for the confusion.

Comment: With the overwriting aspect, that was if it was using `${$foo}` rather than `${$foo}[$sto_name]`.  But in light of your comment I could try `${$foo}[]` . Does that mean that if there's two arrays to be created for 1 date, it will just create `$20160316[0]` and `$20160316[1]` ? That'd work I reckon

Comment: @Anant I just meant I'll have to try that, but if what you suggested means if there's two arrays to be created for 1 date, it will just create `$20160316[0]` and `$20160316[1]` then I think that should work for my requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you said that:-"But then on the `mysqli while` loop it presumably overwrites the first array if there's a second array with the same `date/$foo`"**

So you need to change `${$foo}[$sto_name]` to `${$foo}[$sto_name][]`.

Or

Better would be to use `${$foo}[]` instead of `${$foo}[$sto_name]`

**Note:- It will works fine in both condition:- Either you got single data or multiple data.**

Comment: Using `${$foo}[]=array('sto_name'=>$sto_name, ...` Thank you. :)